# Comparing data between tables in same database

Tags: postgresql

My requirement is i have to compare data between two different tables with same schema in same database ,

For the moment I am making comparison in different fields in same table and if some validation fails error will be stored in one table like :

```
      IF (NEW.vision IS NULL and new.vispres IS NOT NULL)                   
      THEN INSERT INTO exception_detail( noces,exception) VALUES                        
      (new.no,'please check the values if vision is null then vispres should also be null');
    END IF;
```

The same kind of comparison i want to do with two tables for same element (no) eg

```
         IF (TABLE1.NEW.vispres IS NULL and TABLE2.new.vispres IS NOT NULL)                   
      THEN INSERT INTO exception_detail( noces,exception) VALUES                          
      (new.no,'please check the values if vispres is null for number 5 in table 1   then vispres should also be null for number 5 in Table 2 ');
    END IF;
```

Please help
Thank you in advance

Can I do something like :

```
      SELECT q1.* FROM TABLE1 q1
       INNER JOIN TABLE2 q2 ON (q1.noces = q2.noces);
```

I think it will give all the records from both tables where noces is same

In continuation now i want to compare each row of the output, and if data is not same it must throw exception, IS there a possibility like :

```
         foreach row of above output{

          if (q1.name != q2.name)
          Do something ;

        if (q2.address < q1.address)
         Do something ;

         }
```

but it all must be in one query or trigger

Comment: Is this code in an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` trigger?

Comment: its on both      CREATE TRIGGER acui
      AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
       ON acuit
        FOR EACH ROW
       EXECUTE PROCEDURE acu();

Comment: So when you insert or update a record in `acuit`, your trigger is called and the new `acuit` row is available as `NEW`; `TABLE2` does not participate in the update of `acuit` — which row in `TABLE2` do you expect to reference via `TABLE2.new` at that point? You will need to `SELECT` whatever you need from `TABLE2` yourself.

Comment: I want to reference the same row with current number 5 in table2, but if I use select , how can I use it to compare like I am doing right now ? what should I write instead of TABLE2.new.vispres ? Can you please give an example to use select in same situation. Thank you

Comment: please help I did not get my answer exactly

Comment: "The same row with current number 5 in table2" means nothing. It is completely unclear how you would pick the row in `TABLE2` that you want to work with.

Comment: @lanzz: Even I do not know how will I pick the row, I want that complete row from TABLE2 for comparison with TABLE1 in trigger, can I use select * from TBALE2 where number = 5, and store temporarily somewhere and use in trigger?

Comment: somebody please help ...thank u in advance

Comment: Do I need to post this question again to get help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at essentially three cases.

1. ID's the same, but data differs
2. ID in table_a not found in table_b
3. ID in table_b not found in table_a

SQL might look like this:

```
SELECT (r).* FROM ( -- Wrapper query
   SELECT a as r
     FROM table_a a
     JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id AND a <> b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a as r
     FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE b.id IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b AS r
     FROM table_b b
LEFT JOIN table_a a ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.id IS NULL
) t;
```

It might be possible to fold this into a case and a full outer join but this should give you the basic idea.